# PhalconPHP - get specific object with multiple relations

Tags: php, models, phalcon, relation

I have a model, call it Robot, which has multiple manyToMany relationships with other models - Part, Country and Permision. Relation models being RobotsParts, RobotsCountries and RobotsPermissions.

Each robot can have multiple or no parts, countries and permissions linked to them.

To get all the robots with a certain part, PhalconPHP makes it easy. (aliases being properly set in models, of course).

```
$part = Part::findFirstByName("arm");
$robotsWithPart = $part->robots;
```

The same thing applies for robots with a certain country:

```
$country = Country::findFirstByCode("HR");
$robotsWithCountry = $country->robots;
```

But how can one get only robots with a certain part, country and permission?

I've had futile attempts like:

```
$country = Country::findFirstByCode("HR");
$part = Part::findFirstByName("arm");

$robots = $country->getRobots([
    'conditions' => "(partId = :pid:)",
    'bind' => [
        'pid' => $part->id
    ]
]);
```

But, of course, partId is not recognized as it doesn't belong to any of the selected models;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$model->getRelated('model', $parameters = [])` option.
`$parameters = []` works the same as how you would normally query a model. i.e; it takes the parameters `order`, `limit`, `conditions`, ...

```
$country = Country::findFirstByCode("HR");
$part = Part::findFirstByName("arm");

$robots = $country->getRelated('Robot', ['partId = ' . $part->id]);
```

You can find this in [the documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#magic-getters-vs-explicit-methods)

---

**UPDATE**

That sounds like it wouldn't be possible. You will have to call a custom query on your `Robot` model. Something like this:

```
$result = Robot::query()
        ->join('Country', 'Country.id = Robot.countryId')
        ->join('Part', 'Part.robotId = Robot.id')
        ->where('Country.code = :code:')
        ->where('Part.name = :name:')
        ->bind(['code' => 'HR', 'name' => 'arm'])
        ->execute();
```

You can also use the Querybuilder, if you prefer to use that.

Comment: The parameters that getRelated('Robot', [params]) function accepts are only the columns in the Robot model. The rest throw an error "Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception: Column 'partId' doesn't belong to any of the selected models".

Comment: @Vorta, aha, sounds like that wouldnt be possible. You will have to use a custom query. Check my updated answer, it might help you get started!

Comment: Custom query it is. However, a small correction for the above:
`$result = Robot::query()`. Everything else remains the same. I've tested the solution and am getting expected results. Not the prettiest thing, but gets the job done. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer to match your solution ! @Vorta, if it works, it works :)